# Converting pairRDD to dataset in spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

How to create  Spark dataset from pairRDD using java. Could you please help?

Comment: I bookmarked the link, thanks ;-)
@Kiran, what have you tried so far? Have you written a bit of code? If so, what's wrong with it? Ideally, can you provide a minimal snippet of code that allows to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hey Kiran, have you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to go from a dataset to a pairRDD in Java, you first need to convert the dataset to a RDD using `javaRDD()` and then to a `pairRDD` using `mapToPair`.

Here is an example:

```java
//creating a dataset (of rows)
Dataset<Row> ds = spark
    .range(5)
    .select(col("id").alias("x"),
            col("id").multiply(col("id")).alias("y"));
JavaPairRDD<Long, Long> pairRDD = ds
    .javaRDD() // to RDD in Java
    .mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getLong(0), row.getLong(1)));
```